# Добавить в уже существующий объект свойство и положить в него объект redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, объекты, redux, state

У меня имеется такая вложенность в редьюсере

```js
initialState = {
  prop1: {
    props2: {
      prop3: {id: '123', text: '222'},
      prop4: {id: '321', text: '555}
    }
  }
}
```

Мне нужно при срабатывании экшена на добавление задачи получить следующее

```js
initialState = {
  prop1: {
    props2: {
      prop3: {id: '123', text: '222'},
      prop4: {id: '321', text: '555'},
      newprop: {id: '555', text: 'dasdadasd'}
    }
  }
}
```

Как это можно реализовать? Как бы я не пытался у меня постоянно перетирается существующий объект новым свойством, попытка задать новое свойство провалилась, причем свойство по сути у меня совпадает с ID которое будет в объекте, т.к. его я передаю через action.payload[0]

Answer (score 0):

Стандартными средствами, без зависимостей:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
  prop1: {
    ...state.prop1,
    props2: {
      ...state.prop1.props2,
      newprop: { id: '555', text: 'dasdadasd' }
    }
  }
});
```

Для того чтобы избежать копирования вложенных структур по референсу, нужно деструктурировать *все* объектные свойства объекта стейта, *по всем уровням вложенности*.

Я не совсем понял где именно в `action.payload` лежит объектное значение нового свойства, поэтому в примере написал это значение литералом вместо клонирования (вида `{ ...action.payload.data }`).
В том случае, если у значения нового свойства тоже будет вложенность - нужно *глубоко* клонировать его тем же способом, как в примере клонируется стейт.

---

Для сильно сложных/объемных структур, советую использовать глубокое клонирование средствами сторонней библиотеки, например [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).